# 2 Processes listening on the same port - .NET not throwing exception

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, port

The image below shows 2 processes that attempted and successfully bound listen sockets (server) to port 10000 on my local machine:

[image: Sysinternals showing 2 binds on port 10000]

and here's the output of netstat (for confirmation):

```
netstat -a -n | find "10000"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:10000             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

(NB: The javaw.exe process was the first to open the listen socket on 10000).

While I am aware of situations under which multiple processes can indeed listen on the same port [(`SO_REUSEADDR`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352935/how-are-two-processes-listening-to-the-same-port-in-windows-7), there are certain things that bother me in my specific scenario:

1. In my application, I specifically say to .NET that I want an **exclusive** listen socket (`SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`) via

   ```
   listener = new TcpListener(adr, ipport);
   listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;
   ```
2. .NET does **not** throw any kind of exception / error / notification that the port is already in use. In fact, it actually *believes* that everything went fine.
3. My server application never wakes up from the `listener.AcceptTcpClient()` call from this point on. The client application that is supposed to communicate with the server receives a valid connection but is unable to communicate with "my" server (supposedly because it establishes a connection to the "other" process which doesn't speak its "protocol").

In case someone wants to try and reproduce my findings: The 2nd process is the "Helios" release of Eclipse (PHP). But the specific process shouldn't matter here: If one process can do weird things under an OS, so can others.

Any advice on how I can either get an error or prevent such a situation (by means of additional parameters) altogether?

Comment: [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.exclusiveaddressuse.aspx) that the behaviour may depend on your OS (see Remarks there).  Just guessing what to check.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives a more advanced overview over the exclusive address use, but it doesn't help as it doesn't seem to work "as advertised" (I'm on Win7) unless I'm missing something essential.

Comment: I think this depends upon how the other process set up its socket. Specifically, I can't reproduce the issue with any of my existing open sockets. Nevertheless, I agree that you've found a problem with the .NET Framework, assuming it _is_ repeatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you posted in your comment seems to answer your question.

It has to do with the java application binding to the wildcard IP endpoint (`0.0.0.0` ip4; `::` for ip6, or `IPEndpoint.ANY`).  I'm assuming that the `adr` variable in your code snippet above is a specific IP address, and not also a wildcard address.

Take a look at the tables in that article.  It lists the outcomes of trying to bind to either  a specific or wildcard endpoint a second time, with different combinations of socket options.

In short, the Java code is binding on the wildcard `0.0.0.0` endpoint without the `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` socket option. The matrix shows that when this happens, you can successfully bind to a **specific** address and pass requesting exclusive address use.

If you were to try and bind with a wildcard, the table shows that the call would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's not throwing an exception. Although, the docs say `TcpListener`'s constructor doesn't really validate whether the port is open or not, and so, it only throws an `ArgumentException` when the port number is invalid. Other methods, like `Start` will throw a `SocketException` with `ErrorCode` set to `WSAEADDRINUSE` (10048) when the port is already opened by another process (see [Start method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt2x8705.aspx) and [Socket Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

To prevent this, either call `Start` and catch the `SocketException` or use the namespace `System.Net.NetworkInformation` to query for all ports used and figure out if a particular port is available, as in this answer: [In C#, how to check if a TCP port is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to actually enable TCP port sharing - I'm on my phone right now, so best I can do at the moment is drop a link: 
[Net.TCP Port Sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx)

Comment: The article you link to is about the net.tcp:// protocol available in WCF, a Microsoft-custom TCP-derived protocol for communication. It sits "on-top" of TCP...

Comment: Ah, mea culpa - should have read the question more carefully; yeah, TCP sharing won't help you in this case, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.exclusiveaddressuse.aspx - Notice some OS differences regarding ExclusiveAddressUse. Try Run as Administrator. Another thought, try going into your Computer Management -> Services and stopping the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service.