# Serve a Flask app on a sub-url during localhost development

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have a Flask app as backend that serves a REST API and an AngularJS front-end app.

I use Grunt/Livereload to serve the front-end at the address:  `http://localhost:5000/`

Is it possible to serve the Flask app on a sub-url of localhost during development, using `app.run()` or `run_simple` from werkzeug?
Specifically I would like to have the Flask app accessible at the address:  `http://localhost:5000/api`

I found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/rduplain/1705072) but it has the disadvantage of serving a dummy app at `http://localhost:5000/` which uses the address and doesn't let me serve the AngularJS app at that address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that Flask and Yoman are set up you cannot actually do this - it is [possible to have two processes share the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352935/how-are-two-processes-listening-to-the-same-port-in-windows-7), but it is generally done to allow one master process to pass off handling of individual requests to sub-processes, which is not quite what you are doing here. (In general, in production, you would run both the front and back end behind a proxy server like nginx.)

Fortunately, you do not have to re-invent the wheel or run a separate proxy server just to develop your app - there is a Grunt plugin called [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) that will let you proxy requests to a sub-url to another location entirely.  That will let you spin up your Flask backend server on a different port (say port 5001) and proxy requests to `localhost:5000/api` (for example) to `localhost:5001/`:

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 5000,
        hostname: 'localhost'
    },
    proxies: [
        {
            context: '/api',
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 5001,
            https: false,
            changeOrigin: false,
            xforward: false
        }
    ]
}
```

And then you can run your Flask app with `app.run(port=5001)`.

Comment: Thanks after a bit of fiddling I figured out that it wasn't possible to do. Thanks for the solution it's great.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
from flask import Flask
prefix = '/abc'
app = Flask(__name__)

# redefine route
def route(path, *args, **kwargs):
    return _route(prefix + path, *args, **kwargs)
_route = app.route
app.route = route

# Test function
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: That's the same solution adopted in the link I included in my question. Unfortunately `werkzeug.wsgi.DispatcherMiddleware` always expect a main application to be served on the main domain, in this case `http://localhost:5000/`. In other words it seems to expect a main app and a secondary app to be handled in Python. In my case instead I use Yeoman to create and handle the AngularJS front-end hence it would be easier to use grunt/livereload (node.js) to serve the front-end.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer. Sorry.

Comment: No `APPLICATION_ROOT` only applies to sessions, i.e. cookies, see http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2012/1/30/application-root-on-localhost/#67508e2b00f8b798ed0663295d70705d

Comment: Genius! Thanks for this. I did it like this https://gist.github.com/NiklasRosenstein/ba042b87de47c516d78b

Comment: Oh I just noticed that this doesn't update the path of the `/static` route. :(

Comment: Using the `DispatcherMiddleware` method now which is working fine. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/#combining-applications